# SharePoint 2016 - Set Content Approval issue

Tags: workflow, content-approval

I created a work flow to approve the documents in my share point library. I created work flow by doing steps mentioned in the attached image. Here I received an error with status code 409. Then I become to know the Etag is required for the files while doing set content approval action. But Etag is not able to find during search. Please guide me to achieve this.

[image: Flow Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this. In order to use the "set content approval status" action you first must use the "get file metadata" action. Please see below screenshot.

[image]

"Identifier" is output from the "Get item" action.

You can then use the ETAG from this action within your "set content approval status" action.

Hope this helps.